# How to modify values in XSL splitting by comma

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

XSL:

```
<xsl:value-of select="theName" />
```

Sample Values (Last, First Middle, Title):

```
- Fitzerald, John K., MBBS
- Keane, Mike
```

How can I split the `theName`, taking the samples values above, so it displays like this:

```
- John K. Fitzerald MBBS
- Mike Keane
```

Comment: What version of XSLT?

Comment: I am using 2.0.

Comment: Version 1.0 it looks like now

Comment: @Si8 Which XSLT 1.0 processor are you using? It may support  a `tokenize()` function as an extension .

Comment: Help me out please... how do I know the processor? :/

Comment: @Si8 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244370/how-can-i-check-which-xslt-processor-is-being-used-in-solr/25245033#25245033

Answer (score 1):

Here's an XSLT 2.0 option using [`tokenize()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath-functions-20101214/#func-tokenize)...

**XML Input**

```
<doc>
    <theName>Fitzerald, John K., MBBS</theName>
    <theName> Fitzerald , John  K. , MBBS  </theName>
    <theName>Keane, Mike</theName>
</doc>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="theName">
    <xsl:variable name="tokens" 
      select="for $token in tokenize(.,',') return normalize-space($token)"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="($tokens[2],$tokens[1],$tokens[3])" separator=" "/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<doc>
   <theName>John K. Fitzerald MBBS</theName>
   <theName>John K. Fitzerald MBBS</theName>
   <theName>Mike Keane</theName>
</doc>
```

Comment: I have `<xsl:value-of select="theName" />` inside a XSLT file already so just use the template?

Comment: @Si8 - The only thing that is different is the context. You can either add the template and do `<xsl:apply-templates select="theName"/>` instead of `xsl:value-of` or you can just add the `xsl:variable` (change `tokenize(.,',')` to: `tokenize(theName,',')`) and replace the `xsl:value-of` with what I'm using. If that still isn't working, please update your question with an example XML input and output.

Comment: My `xml` version at top says 1.0, so I am guessing I was wrong when I said it is 2.0? :/

Comment: @Si8 - Not necessarily. That would be the XML version. The stylesheet version is specified in the `version` attribute of the `xsl:stylesheet` element. However, even if the stylesheet version is 2.0, you still need a 2.0 processor. What XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: Nevermind... it is 1.0... `<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">`

Comment: I added the template as separate and it is giving me an error... your solution was perfect but unf looks like I can't use it.